# Coffee machine that adds condiments dynamically

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I want to make a coffee machine class which can produce coffee with condiments I like, and the price of the final coffee can be easily calculated.

I chose decorator pattern in my design. I've tried making the fields private to follow the principle of making scope as small as possible, but when I implemented the concrete decorator, the `getName()` caused trouble, I can not use `getName()` of the beverage in `getName()` of Milk(ConcreteDecorator). So finally I chose protected.

I've considered [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/143739/249025) about using private over protected, but I don't know which one should be better in my implementation. This is a small program but I need some advice about the big picture which I should keep in mind.

So, any advice about any layer of the design of my code is appreciated.

```
public abstract class Beverage {
    protected final String name;

    public Beverage(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public abstract Double getCost();
}

public class HouseBlend extends Beverage {
    public HouseBlend() {
        super("HouseBlend");
    }

    @Override
    public Double getCost() {
        return 1.5;
    }
}

public abstract class Dairy extends Beverage {
    protected final Beverage beverage;

    public Dairy(String name, Beverage beverage) {
        super(name);
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public Beverage getBeverage() {
        return beverage;
    }

    public abstract String getName();
}

public class Milk extends Dairy {
    public Milk(Beverage beverage) {
        super("Milk", beverage);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name + "-flavored " + beverage.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Double getCost() {
        return 1.0 + beverage.getCost();
    }
}

public class Butter extends Dairy {
    public Butter(Beverage beverage) {
        super("Butter", beverage);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name + "-above " + beverage.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Double getCost() {
        return 0.5 + beverage.getCost();
    }
}

public abstract class Sweet extends Beverage {
    protected final Beverage beverage;

    public Sweet(String name, Beverage beverage) {
        super(name);
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

    public Beverage getBeverage() {
        return beverage;
    }

    public abstract String getName();
}

public class Sugar extends Sweet {

    public Sugar(Beverage beverage) {
        super("Sugar", beverage);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Strong-" + name + "ed " + beverage.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Double getCost() {
        return 0.2 + beverage.getCost();
    }
}
```

UML: [image: Decorator Pattern UML by @N1ng]

Comment: It's [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com), a plug-in for Eclipse, and the UML-part is free, for your interest. @JudeNiroshan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would remove the `name` field entirely, and instead inline it into the `getName()` method.
That way you can implement the `getName()` similar to how you implemented `getCost()`.

Concretely this means your `getName()` method from `Beverage` becomes abstract just like the other abstract classes.

```
public abstract String getName();
```

The base beverage (`HouseBlend`) then implements the method as:

```
public String getName() {
    return "HouseBlend";
}
```

And similarly the decorator classes implement it as such:

```
public String getName() {
    return "Milk-flavored " + beverage.getName();
}
```

You can fill in the implementation for the other decorators.